# Third elsif statement generates nil and not desired output

Tags: ruby, testing

Performing a BDD tutorial and the test requires that a word that has two consonants at the beginning of a word be translated into pig latin. It is the the second elsif statement is where I am having trouble. The code is as follows:

```
def translate(arg)

    vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    vowel_word = "ay"

    consonant = ["z", "b", "t", "g", "h"]
    consonant_word = "ay"

    if vowel.include?(arg[0]) == true
        return arg + vowel_word
    elsif consonant.include?(arg[0]) == true
        foo = arg[1,6]
        return foo + arg[0] + consonant_word
    elsif (consonant.include?(arg[0]) == true) and (consonant.include?(arg[1]) == true)
        foo = arg[2, 5]
        return foo + arg[0] + arg[1] + consonant_word
    end
end

translate("apple")
translate("banana")
translate("cherry")
```

My problem is with the third condition. The output is nil, not 'errychay' which is what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should use `or` instead of `and`. More about boolean operators in Ruby you can look [here](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/8-control-structures/lessons/43-boolean-expressions-in-ruby). Also, i advise you to do some refactoring:

```
def translate(arg)
  vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
  vowel_word = "ay"
  consonant = ["z", "b", "t", "g", "h"]
  consonant_word = "ay"

  if vowel.include?(arg[0])
    arg + vowel_word
  elsif consonant.include?(arg[0])
    foo = arg[1,6]
    foo + arg[0] + consonant_word
  elsif consonant.include?(arg[0]) || consonant.include?(arg[1])
    foo = arg[2, 5]
    foo + arg[0] + arg[1] + consonant_word
  end
end
```

Note, that `include?` method returns `true` of `false`, so you may omit `== true`. Also, Ruby automatically returns last string of `if..else` statement, so you can omit it too.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much, this worked like a charm.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about this post, but it should be a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: Why? Question was `The output is nil, not 'errychay' which is what I want`. I answered on question, and gave link for more details about boolean operators.

Comment: @sawa it answered my question and got my code to behave the way I intended

Answer (score 1):

It is because your

```
consonant = ["z", "b", "t", "g", "h"]
```

is not a full consonant list, particularly it does not include the `arg[0]` of `"cherry"`, which is `"c"`. So `"cherry"` satisfies neither `vowel.include?(arg[0])` nor `consonant.include?(arg[0])`, nor any of the three `if`/`elsif` conditions, and the condition block returns `nil`.